# keep exif information after adjust size of UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, metadata, exif, image-resizing

I am trying resize a `UIImage` and keep the original EXIF metadata.
However, it looks like no straight forward method available now.

I tried `CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex` to get original EXIF metadata but I have no idea how can I write it into target image.

However, i've notice that `ALAsset` library function have related stuff like `writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum`, but I wonder if that would be helpful for my resize requirement ..

Any clue ?